# WPF Chart Toolkit. Bind Label's content in ColumnDataPoint to ViewModel DataPoint Property

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I have an extended `ObservableCollection` that holds the datapoints plus some extra information

```
public class ExtendedCollection : ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string,int>>>
{

}
```

Then I also have a ViewModel holding the `ColumnSeries` that uses this `ExtendedCollection`

```
private ExtendedCollection columnValues = new ExtendedCollection();
public ExtendedCollection ColumnValues
{
    get
    {
        return columnValues;
    }
    set
    {
        columnValues = value;
        PropChanged("ColumnValues");
    }
}
```

Finally, I am trying to display the collection items' `Value.Key` on a label templated in each datapoint's column

```
<chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries Name="columnSeries" DependentValuePath="Value.Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnValues}">
    <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
        <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries}},Path=DataContext.ColumnValues.Value.Key, Mode=TwoWay}"></Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
</chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries>
```

I've tried many different `Binding`s for the `Label`'s `Content` but none works. How can I link the `Content` to the `Value.Key` of `ColumnDataPoint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExtendedCollection` property has no `Value` property but the `DataContext` of the column has:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Value.Key}"></Label>
```